# get image related info and images

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, image

what would be the best approach to get image related info and images like "different colors" using angularjs.

I am developing shopping cart for garments and using `ng-repeat` for showing images. Now have to open a single image info when I click specific image and that will be open in another page.

My problem is that, i can either:

- get data image related from json file
- or `$scope` custom array.

But how can I get images? also images can be two three or one? should I use push function for adding related images and info for product detail page?

My page looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of site]

Comment: You should do this in your backend. Such kind of process is high cost based.

Comment: Means can't get help here?

Comment: What is your backend based on?

Comment: using visual studio iis express

Comment: Which technology/language?

Comment: c# javascript(angularjs)

Comment: Allright, you should look for a C# based solution "c# find colors in image". Iam sure you will find a solution based on google.

Comment: no its to much dynamic approach. i have to add image thumbnails and a medium image using angularjs and then zoom it as i shown in screenshot

Comment: Good luck by extracting the colors of an image on client side.